# For what are the tables meta in wordpress database?

Tags: wordpress, database-schema

For what are the tables meta in wordpress database? some tables in the database of wordpress are connected to a table with the same name refering the table connected and ending the name with the word "meta". what mean those tables, what is their role? for example the table wp_users has wp_usermeta, wp_posts has wp_postmeta, etc

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is additional information that WP and plugins can use for storing data in a "key - value" fashion. That is why it has only meta_key and meta_value columns. This way Wordpress tries to stay with flexible database structure.

Imagine you want to make a wp blog for cooking and recipes. You can associate a food recipe to each post by putting it into the `wp_postsmeta` table

`wp_usersmeta` is the same thing for users - any additional data or user preferences you want to store can be put inside this table.